# how to write in html dom

Tags: php, html, dom

I have created web builder editor with drag and drop and then convert into full HTML page using HTML DOM, when I pressed save button and is works great.

What it does is that if I want to drag the form into the editor and is only drag form, and then once click save button is convert to a new page under HTML code and save file name  for samples like file_name-html or file_name.php

Part of this web builder I also want to add new code allow me to drag one of PHP code box `<?PHP include '' ?>` into the editor and save it.

But is because HTML DOM is only worked in full HTML code and will not add PHP code in HTML do is giving me errors I'm trying to figure out how to add one small PHP code in HTML Dom allow me to drag and drop of  into the editor before convert into the HTML code and save under .php file so that way it will create one line of PHP code and rest HTML codes.

I'm not really good at HTML DOM code, does any one can help me how to write code to allow me to print  when I drag-drop into the editor.

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body><?php include 'file-name.php' ?></body></html>');
```

can anyone can help me how to write that code start from

```
function name ()
{
    $html = str_get_html('<html><body><?php include 'file-name.php' ?></body></html>');
}
```

many thanks.

Comment: You can't add `<?php` tags inside strings and your concatenation is wrong.

Comment: PHP is not recursively embeddable/executable.  `$var = '<?php echo .... '` does NOT execute an echo command. All that does it store a string with the characters `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do is escape your quotes to write the text file and save as a `.php` file for calling by the PHP interpreter later.

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body><?php include \'file-name.php\'; ?></body></html>');
var_dump($html->save());
```

Result:

```
string(167) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><?php include 'file-name.php'; ?></body></html>
"
```

Demo Using `DOMDocument`: http://ideone.com/hWC6UR

If you're wanting the PHP Interpreter to render the include file and save as an `.html` file, I suggest using Output Buffering.

```
<?php 
/** file-name.php **/ 
echo 'Hello World';
```

```
ob_start();
include 'file-name.php';
$data = ob_get_clean();
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>'. $data .'</body></html>');
var_dump($html->save());

string(167) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
"
```